# Add additional DC (WIN 2008 R2) to Branch Office

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have a DC with DNS server installed in head office, we have a RODC with DNS server installed in branch office A.  we are now would like to add an additional DC (NOT RODC) to branch office A, but there are three options in "Additional DC Options" and we do not know which option we have to select "DNS server", "Global catalog" and "RODC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question because there's not a lot of detail but this is just asking you how you'd like to configure this new domain controller. Do you want it to be a DNS server? Do you want it to be a Global Catalog? I'm guessing the plan is not to have an RODC since you already have one there, but those are recommended if the site does not have a secure computer closet or data center.

You only have to have the DNS service on one domain controller technically, but in all honesty with most scenarios I set them up as both a DNS server AND as a Global Catalog.

DNS for the local site if there are enough users, and Global Catalog so it can answer queries through 3268/3269 TCP (GC queries). The GC is a read-only port that returns partial data for your entire forest, if you have a multi-domain environment this is especially useful.

Old documentation says you should only use it as you need to, but this was based on slow connections in days gone by, these days with reliable network speeds that's usually a non-issue.

Comment: you should also remove the RODC.

Comment: In addition to Jim's comment, I want to be clear about my statement above regarding the secure closet or data center. If someone were able to physically access and copy your RWDC's drives/make an image, or steal the server, they could control your entire organization.